# Running time of piece of Java code

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to figure out the running time of the following snippet of Java code:

```
static void counter(int N) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j += 1) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Just for clarification, the running time would be \Theta(N^2), right? The outer loop runs N times and the inner loop runs N-j times for each iteration of j. Putting this together gives \Theta(N^2).

Comment: You are right: `t = N - 1 + N - 2 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = (N - 1) * (N) / 2 = Theta(N**2)`

Comment: Yes. You are right. PS : I would call it *Time complexity* instead of *Running Time*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Theta(n^2)` is correct.

The inner loop runs `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 + 0` iterations, which [adds up to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) `n * (n-1) / 2 = 0.5*n^2 - 0.5*n = Theta(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

Counting the number of iterations the inner loop runs for each iteration of the outer loop, you get :

N-1 + N-2 + N-3 + ... + 1 = ((N-1)*N)/2 = Theta(N^2)